# Is there any way to interrupt a pending Windows 10 update from Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-10, windows-8.1, graphics-card, windows-update

A friend has a PC running Windows 8.1. Recently, the auto-updater downloaded a patch which installs Windows 10 (possibly [KB3035583](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3035583)).

The update has been applied, and requires a restart; the trouble is that this update is known to brick this PC's hardware configuration because of an issue caused by the graphics card; specifically, it's a very old graphics card, a GeForce 6600GT LE.

Unfortunately, neither my friend nor I have a newer graphics card available, and this PC doesn't have any backups.

Is there any way to roll back this update before it gets fully applied on reboot?

Comment: ...it's not too late to back up the important stuff now. :-(